# why round off of 45.5 is 46 while for 10.5 it is 10?

Tags: python, rounding-unit

I was trying to round off two numbers in python 3.10

```
round(45.5)
```

and I got the result as `46` but when I tried to round off 10.5 :

```
round(10.5)
```

I got the result as `10`

why round off of 45.5 is 46 while for 10.5 it is 10 ?

I could not understand this.

Is it python that follows certain rules for truncation, or is it a Math that says to round the different numbers following certain rules?

If later is correct then what these rules are?

Comment: Probably using the "round to even" technique.

Comment: Rounding is done toward the even choice. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round

Comment: Ig It is an convention (I was told in my 11th grade ). It state that in I.5 (I is integer).   If I is odd then its roundoff is I+1 and if I is even the its roundoff is I

Comment: There are a lot of rounding systems, though this one is pretty standard.    See [this](https://realpython.com/python-rounding/)

Comment: @lulu - thanks. but that article still does not clear the doubts that I have. **Is it python that follows certain rules for truncation, or is it a Math that says to round the different numbers following certain rules? ** if later is correct then what these rules are?

Comment: As I say, "Math" doesn't say anything.  There are a number of standard systems for rounding, and "round to even" is a common one.  It has the advantage of (sometimes) being less biased than other schemes.  But there are other conventions.  In any situation where precision is critical, you should make sure you know what scheme is being followed.

Comment: “Rounding” is just a set of arbitrary rules used to simplify data/calculations. It is not defined in Math. So “math” does not “say” _any_ thing about rounding.

Comment: @parthsachdeva - This clears all my doubts! thanks so much for the explanation. :)